# Get Services On Open Port

Tags: penetration-test, nmap, web-service, ports

Is it possible to get a list of services running on an open port?

E.g. I am connected to port 80 with netcat and I want to get services that are listening.

Comment: Do you want a list of services running on a local machine, or a remote machine?

Comment: Do you mean multiple services on a single port?

Comment: all services on a single port on a remote machine

Comment: @JohnThomson Have you ever tried setting two services to listen on the same port? The OS will throw an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about nmap with the -sV option? It gives pretty decent results at least as long as the service admins don't actively disguise the protocols, even if services are running on non-standard ports. Output looks like this:

```
Interesting ports on X.X.X.X:
PORT      STATE  SERVICE          VERSION
22/tcp    open   ssh              OpenSSH 5.2 (protocol 2.0)
25/tcp    open   smtp             Sendmail 8.14.3/8.14.3
80/tcp    open   http             Apache httpd 2.2.11 ((Fedora))
111/tcp   open   rpcbind
```

Comment: +1 well look at that, it does exist. Do you have any idea how it works? How on earth does it know what version of what software is running !?

Comment: This is called "banner grabbing". The server sends information to the client, e.g. in an http header. Similar for other protocols, server says "hey, I'm software X, version Y". Security aware admins will either remove the banner completely or just have it say "I'm an apache" or "this is an smtp daemon" not disclosing more information. So if banner grabbing is not good enough for your purpose (which you haven't told us) then you need sth that analyses other aspects of the protocols like how long certain activities take, etc. I'm not aware of any software that does this.